# How to process delayed jobs before they reach available_at?

Tags: laravel

Let say i delayed bunch of jobs for next hour, How can i process them before they reach the `available_at` time ? I mean in some condition in my app i need process immediately all delayed jobs, Is there anything in artisan ?

Comment: database driver ?

Comment: Yes‌ ‍ ‎‌ ‍ ‎‌ ‍ ‎‌ ‍ ‎‌ ‍ ‎

Comment: @ml59 note that i dont want to mainpulate `available_at` column